# Fusion Charts Server side upload

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, fusioncharts

Trying Server-side exporting using fusion charts.. works well with FF. however internet explorer says 
Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later. "

Help appreciated in advance...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be a bit late to answer this, but to me it seems that you must have put the script inside the DIV where the chart is supposed to render. Try once putting the script outside and after the DIV.

I had also faced this issue earlier.